# I want to make the block's a little bit transparent and bright

Tags: animation

I want to make a lyric video. On the picture their 
is something like a frame where the text then flies through. I want these blocks to be a bit transparent, but you still see them. It would also be cool if they were a bit like glowing. Thx for our help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Change to cycles render
2. Select the object and make a new material for it
3. Open node editor and delete the diffuse material
4. Add a mix shader, emission node and a transparent BSDF and connect them like they are connected in the image
5. The strength on the emission node is the glow strength of the object
6. The Fac on the mix shader is the transparency of the object: 1.0 is invisible and 0.0 is not any transparent

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I don't know hot it works in Blender 2.8 you know it there too?

Comment: No sorry, I haven't upgraded to blender 2.8. But I think it should be pretty similar.

Comment: Okey thank you if somone knows in 2.8 would it be cool if he could explain it to me.